# Load a CSV dataset with header lines and "?" for missing values

Tags: python, csv, numpy, missing-data

I want to load my [dataset (link to external page)](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Cervical+cancer+%28Risk+Factors%29#) from a `.csv` file with the NumPy function `loadtxt`. The dataset contains floats. However, the columns have headers and there are missing datas (materialized by '?').

How can I deal with these problems?

Comment: [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) has `missing_values` and `skip_header`. But without having (parts of) your file it's impossible to give more guidance (at least for me).

Comment: @MSeifert Yes, actually it looks nice. My dataset is the following : http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Cervical+cancer+%28Risk+Factors%29#

Comment: numpy.loadtxt(fname, dtype=<type 'float'>,skiprows=0), this will remove headers. Missing data depends on your data set, you can deal with both the problems effectively with pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the dataset you linked in the comments you could use [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) which allows to specify which values are considered missing (`'?'`) and how many rows to skip because it's the "header" (`1`):

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',', missing_values=['?'], skip_header=1)
array([[ 18.,   4.,  15., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 15.,   1.,  14., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 34.,   1.,  nan, ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       ..., 
       [ 25.,   2.,  17., ...,   0.,   1.,   0.],
       [ 33.,   2.,  24., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 29.,   2.,  20., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

But maybe better suited for this kind of task is [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> pd.read_csv(filename, na_values='?')
     Age  Number of partners  First intercourse  ...
0     18                 4.0               15.0   
1     15                 1.0               14.0   
2     34                 1.0                NaN   
3     52                 5.0               16.0   
4     46                 3.0               21.0   
5     42                 3.0               23.0   
6     51                 3.0               17.0   
7     26                 1.0               26.0   
8     45                 1.0               20.0   
9     44                 3.0               15.0   
10    44                 3.0               26.0   
11    27                 1.0               17.0   
12    45                 4.0               14.0   
13    44                 2.0               25.0   
14    43                 2.0               18.0   
...
```